# Sorting fetch results by Bool attribute in CoreData Swift 4

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, swift4

I am creating a ToDo list app and would like to sort the tableviewcontroller by priority.  if the task is important i would like it on top of the todo list, if it is not important than i would like it under/after the important tasks.  I have been trying to figure out how to sort this but have not been able to.  Appreciate some help.

```
class ToDoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var toDos : [ToDoCoreData] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getToDos()
}

func getToDos() {
    if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext{

        if let coreDataToDos = try? context.fetch(ToDoCoreData.fetchRequest()) as? [ToDoCoreData] {
            if let theToDos = coreDataToDos {
                toDos = theToDos
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    let toDo = toDos[indexPath.row]

    if let name = toDo.name {

        if toDo.important {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "❗️" + name
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = toDo.name
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Core Data can fetch items sorted by given sort descriptors. And your method `getToDos` is *overguarded*. The `context` is supposed to be non-optional and a fetch with generic fetch request returns a non-optional array of the generic `NSManagedObject` subclass on success. Handle the error in a `do -  catch` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `getToDos()` function like that:

```
func getToDos() {
    if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext{

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ToDoCoreData> = ToDoCoreData.fetchRequest()
        let descriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "important", ascending: true)] // try true/false

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = descriptors

        if let coreDataToDos = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) {
            if let theToDos = coreDataToDos {
                toDos = theToDos
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting "Use of undeclared type 'NSFetchRequest' error

Comment: add `import CoreData` in the top of file

Comment: that worked sort of.  That got the error out.  But it is not sorting my list.  It is not bringing Important stuff to the top.  not sure if this matters but "important" is a boolean in my ToDoCoreData entity

Comment: Try `NSSortDescriptor(key: "important", ascending: false)`

Comment: Just change `true` to `false` for `ascending` parameter, it will definitely bring your important items to the top.